# properrty = undefined when I load

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, angular16

I have an abstract class called `DynamicGridClass`, which includes an optional property `showGlobalActions?: boolean?`. This class is extended by `MatDynamicGridComponent`, which is a child component. Within `MatDynamicGridComponent`, I have an `@Input()` property defined as `showGlobalActions: boolean = true.`

When I load `MatDynamicGridComponent` through an HTML element, it correctly takes the value I pass to it. For example: `[showGlobalActions]="false"`. Additionally, if I don't explicitly pass any value, it automatically defaults to true as defined in `@Input() showGlobalActions: boolean = true.`

The issue arises when I load `MatDynamicGridComponent` via routing. In this scenario, the `showGlobalActions` variable appears as undefined.

```
{
  path: 'auth/resources',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: MatDynamicGridComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'resources',
        gridId: 'admin_auth_resource'
      },
    },
    {
      path: 'resources-form/:mode',
      component: AuthResourcesFormComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'resources-form'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

when I load `MatDynamicGridComponent` via routing. In this scenario, the `showGlobalActions` variable appears as undefined

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging, else share the code for the components, the minimal reproducible code is enough!

Answer (score 0):

You should give showGlobalActions as input to route data like this:

```
    {
  path: 'auth/resources',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: MatDynamicGridComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'resources',
        gridId: 'admin_auth_resource',
        showGlobalActions: true,
      },
    },
    {
      path: 'resources-form/:mode',
      component: AuthResourcesFormComponent,
      data: {
        title: 'resources-form',
        showGlobalActions: true,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can access it in your MatDynamicGridComponent ngOnInit :

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.showGlobalActions = window.history.state.showGlobalActions;
}
```